# Dockerising pelican project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pelican

I'm trying to dockerise my pelican site project. I've created a **docker-compose.yml** file and a **Dockerfile**.

However, every time I try to build my project (`docker-compose up`) I get the following errors for both pip install and npm install:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
...
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

The directory structure of the project is as follows:

```
 - **Dockerfile**
 - **docker-compose.yml**
 - content/ 
 - pelican-plugins/ 
 - src/
   - Themes/
   - Pelican config files
   - requirements.txt
   - gulpfile.js
   - package.js
```

All the pelican makefiles etc. are in the src directory.

I'm trying to load the content, src, and pelican-plugins directories as volumes so I can modify them on my local machine for the docker container to use.

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /src
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

# Install Node.js 8 and npm 5
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Set the locale
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN npm install
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV SRV_DIR=/src
RUN chmod +x $SRV_DIR

RUN make clean
VOLUME /src/output
RUN make devserver
RUN gulp
```

And here is my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - ./content:/content
    - ./src:/src
    - ./pelican-plugins:/pelican-plugins
volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

It definitely looks like I have set up my volumes directories properly in dockerfiles...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might it be a case sensitivity issue? Try renaming Requirements.txt to requirements.txt

Comment: Sorry that's a typo here. I've updated to lowercase -- I'm using lowercase r for requirements in my project. I've updated the question above for clarity. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile doesn't `COPY` (or `ADD`) any files at all, so the `/src` directory is empty.

You can verify this yourself.  When you run `docker build` it will print out output like:

```
Step 13/22 : ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
 ---> Running in 3ab80c3741f8
Removing intermediate container 3ab80c3741f8
 ---> d240226b6600
Step 14/22 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 1d31955d5b28
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
```

The last line in each step with just a hex number is actually a valid image ID that's the final result of running each step, and you can then:

```
% docker run --rm -it d240226b6600 sh
# pwd
/src
# ls
```

To fix this you need a line in the Dockerfile like

```
COPY . .
```

You probably also need to change into the `src` subdirectory to run `npm install` and the like as you've shown your directory layout.  This can look like:

```sh
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
# Either put "cd" into the command itself
# (Each RUN command starts a fresh container at the current WORKDIR)
RUN cd src && npm install
# Or change WORKDIRs
WORKDIR /src/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /src
```

Remember that everything in the `Dockerfile` happens before any setting in `docker-compose.yml` outside the `build:` block is even considered.  Environment variables, volume mounts, and networking options for a container have no effect on the image build sequence.

In terms of Dockerfile style, your `VOLUME` declaration will have some tricky unexpected side effects and probably is unnecessary; I'd remove it.  Your Dockerfile is also missing the `CMD` that the container should run.  You should also combine `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` into single commands; the way Docker layer caching works and the way the Debian repositories work, it's very easy to wind up with a cached package index that names files from a week ago that don't exist any more.

While the setup you're describing is fairly popular, it also essentially hides *everything* the Dockerfile does with your local source tree.  The `npm install` you're describing here, for example, will be a no-op because the volume mount will hide `/src/src/node_modules`.  I generally find it easier to just run `python`, `npm`, *etc.* locally while I'm developing, rather than write and debug this 50-line YAML file and run `sudo docker-compose up`.

Comment: Yep, I think that was it but have some other errors. But I'll raise a separate stackoverflow question about that if necessary. Thanks!